# Hide elements with ng-change Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to show/hide element in form with ng-change or whatever you suggest . here is my **html**:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
    <select ng-model="myDropDown" ng-change="changeState(0)">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
    </select>

    <div class="row-container">
        first One
        <span class="sp-right">       
            <label>
                1
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="sp-left">
        <input type="text">
        </span>


    <div class="row-container">
        second One
        <span class="sp-right">       
            <label>
                2
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="sp-left">
        <input type="text">
        </span>
```

for example i want to show first one when user click on option 1 .
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgsVw/41/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `ng-change`, just use `ng-if` (or `ng-show`) to inspect the model's state:

```
<div class="row-container" ng-if="myDropDown == 'one'">

<div class="row-container" ng-if="myDropDown == 'two'">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgsVw/43/) (with correct closing tags so that it actually works).

Comment: Just check whether the model value is `null`.

Comment: no i mean for form, when page loads up the first one appears for example

Comment: Use `||` to combine both conditions. AngularJS expressions are almost like JavaScript expressions, so they're pretty powerful.

Comment: ng-if="myDropDown == 'one' || !myDropDown"

Answer (score 2):

I would use [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch). If you want to show a div if none is selected then you can use `ng-switch-default`. If you want to default one of the div's below, then remove `ng-switch-when=` and replace it `ng-switch-default`

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Controller" ng-switch on="myDropDown">
    <select ng-model="myDropDown">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
    </select>

    <div class="row-container" ng-switch-when="one">
        first One
        <span class="sp-right">       
            <label>
                1
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="sp-left">
        <input type="text">
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="row-container" ng-switch-when="two">
        second One
        <span class="sp-right">       
            <label>
                2
            </label>
        </span>
        <span class="sp-left">
        <input type="text">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QNdMxmYjR5LhsNvsHPpJ?p=preview

Comment: for default value can i use something you wrote above ?

Comment: <div class="row-container" ng-switch-when="one" ng-switch-default> something like this ?

Comment: No. Just remove ng-switch-when="one": <div class="row-container"  ng-switch-default>